# Is it possible to get a direct audio file link from Soundcloud without JS

Tags: html, html5-audio, soundcloud

I've seen many posts about using JS to embed SoundCloud tracks with API links, but I'm wondering if there is any possible way to use only the `<audio>` and a SoundCloud file link in HTML?

The reason I need this is because I'm using Google Sheets as a widget for my website to display a list of audio files from different sources and using other sites and getting the mp3 link and throwing it in the list for the template works well but I can't do that with SoundCloud.

[**Preview of widget here**](https://awesome-table.com/-LrllYFUFv1c2KG5s9oH/view)

I know this is the URL I need:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TRACKID/stream?client_id=CLIENTID

I've tried inspecting the web page for this information, and it's not provided. I can only get the track ID.

My google sheet's template is connected to an app called **awesome-table** so I can put down a long list of data without needing to manually write the HTML each time so I need to make it a uniform process.

Each cell is referred to as {{URL}} in the following example

`<audio controls> <source src="{{URL}}" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>`

**The additional details, such as the third-party applications, are just to explain why I'm doing it this way. The question is simply how to get the right data of a Soundcloud track in a way I can directly apply** `<audio controls> <source src="(soundcloud track here)" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>`

Comment: Any luck just using the embedded link for each track? As, the embedded URL supplied by soundcloud is just the page URL: `https://soundcloud.com/nlechoppa/camelot`.Would that work for your application?

Comment: Else maybe this thread will help: https://community.soundcloud.com/podcasting-230062/need-the-direct-url-to-my-soundcloud-hosted-mp3-is-there-a-permalink-to-the-mp3-file-6911194

Comment: I tried the embedded link and it grayed out the audio controls and wouldn't work. https://soundcloud.com/deadseed/risen for instance. I'll look at that thread now

Comment: I think they've made it impossible on purpose.

Comment: Honestly - probably

Comment: It works IF I create an RSS feed for it, therefore if I need any song from soundcloud, the artist would have had to do the same. But it's better than nothing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

sorry if I am kind of late, but here is the correct answer:
Go copy the song URL (not the search result, be careful!)
Now, if you have VLC Media Player downloaded, open the app.
Press CTRL+N and paste it into the box.
Hit enter.
Your song will now load.
Rightclick the song name (be sure you are in playlist view in VLC) and click information (i).

On the bottom there should be a box with the text: File location.
Rightclick the box, click select all, and CTRL+C.
Now, this is your direct mp3 link.
This is mine.

[https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/gesLueRDE5tg.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vZ2VzTHVlUkRFNXRnLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MjIzMDY2Mzh9fX1dfQ__&Signature=L3tgjRJ2nnUP-9qOUBuSi9cJMQL-4aaLniOegTn2z~jnIfTrfr8oJ~JMzjiOLZHCe-sVbIaSiWt3hDEOhlf1YVLj71XF~qxV~l9LpMVtIf-V0ajRkVSBxtL8da1CVEzz4GV9~8K7twCjQhHpInHJp6tCGXU7xKb3IQ2MGVzUYX1yVhI0iBtv30ww6oDCW9MKX2qgn3dFBZ~Aw4dbLu0ba4ZnFdnto8bHZVBqqq0kY9Z5CaTmm1ikvssu37XkiFPH8b8nPI6pBfS7XvAH2M3R~pKLXIGSphlfG11VZVpXxArCcDni~WPUoQpy3S5zba6R5-KkOdM5O2FN5feJouOhAA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI6TU7MMXM5DG6EPQ](https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/gesLueRDE5tg.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vZ2VzTHVlUkRFNXRnLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MjIzMDY2Mzh9fX1dfQ__&Signature=L3tgjRJ2nnUP-9qOUBuSi9cJMQL-4aaLniOegTn2z%7EjnIfTrfr8oJ%7EJMzjiOLZHCe-sVbIaSiWt3hDEOhlf1YVLj71XF%7EqxV%7El9LpMVtIf-V0ajRkVSBxtL8da1CVEzz4GV9%7E8K7twCjQhHpInHJp6tCGXU7xKb3IQ2MGVzUYX1yVhI0iBtv30ww6oDCW9MKX2qgn3dFBZ%7EAw4dbLu0ba4ZnFdnto8bHZVBqqq0kY9Z5CaTmm1ikvssu37XkiFPH8b8nPI6pBfS7XvAH2M3R%7EpKLXIGSphlfG11VZVpXxArCcDni%7EWPUoQpy3S5zba6R5-KkOdM5O2FN5feJouOhAA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI6TU7MMXM5DG6EPQ)

DONT KNOW ABOUT THE LINK VALIDITY LENGHT YET!!!
Viktor

Comment: for me it was the m3u link i.e. https://cf-hls-media.sndcdn.com/playlist/MT8ArhctMP3V.128.mp3/playlist.m3u8?... but i then selected Convert -> to MP3 and voila!

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only way to do this is if the author has enabled RSS feed for the track and by using that RSS URL in the audio source.

`http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/example.mp3`