# Audio File To Play On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link to an audio file stored at soundcloud dot com, and an invisible easter egg icon on my website, which becomes visible on hover. I also want that audio file to be played on click, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I've also tried to put .alert() instead of .play(), and it works just fine.

```js
let audio = document.getElementById("audio")
let icon = document.getElementById("ee-icon")
icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio.play()
})
```

```css
#ee-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#ee-icon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="ee-icon" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fVimwBNrxw1M1hM7oIgqhTanZCXr5wl2hAZ6o_YCXKjpimv8Wd1_Wdtgh0Usk7yn4gAS3 PLgsARgxM97P82igLGqXIGe8lTeE63v7VtUlVa1MmdvqZrhdPsIJwp7PGRnoEWuL_ve0A=s24-p-k" alt="easter-egg">
<audio id="audio" src="https://on.soundcloud.com/jNk4g"></audio>
<!-- WARNING! LOUD SOUND -->
```

Comment: The src  is not valid audio resource url, but the soundcloud page.

Comment: This can work in the general case of "there's an audio file at this publically accessible URL", but if you try loading that URL in a private window you'll see that it's a webpage rather than an audio file. There is some [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58599893/21146235) about accessing SoundCloud files directly, but in this case your easiest option would appear to be a [SoundCloud widget](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing) which may not be the lightweight easter egg you were hoping for.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Maybe any suggestions on public repositories with direct links to audio, please? Even ChatGPT couldn't give me any options)